# I cannot turn off lazy loading in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I'm aware that lazy-loading 'on' is the default setting in NHibernate. I switched lazy-loading off, using mapping-by-code, for the entity (Student) and the collection (Comments) contained within an entity. However a test including the use of SQL-Profiler shows that it does not load the collection from the database when the entity is accessed via a Session.Get(). I see only a 'Select' to get the entity (Student) from the Db. No 'Join' or 'Selects' to the collection table (Comments). Am I missing something? I'm using NH version 5.

Mapping:

```
using NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Conformist;
using NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode;

namespace Infrastructure.Repository.NH.Tests
{
    public class StudentSubclassMapping: JoinedSubclassMapping<Student>
    {
        public StudentSubclassMapping()
        {
            Lazy(false);
            Property(student => student.EnrollmentDate);

            List(student => student.Comments,
                listMapper =>
                { listMapper.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);},
                relationMapper =>
                     relationMapper.Element());
        }
    }
}
```

Domain:

```
public class Student : Contact
{
    public virtual DateTime? EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<string> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Test:

```
    public void Get_TestToCheckIfLazyLoadingIsTurnedOff()
    {
        using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var student = session.Get<Student>(2);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested this with NHibernate 5.0.3 and it seems to be working properly:

```
NHibernate: SELECT student0_.student_key as id1_0_0_, student0_.EnrollmentDate as enrollmentdate2_1_0_ FROM Student student0_ inner join Contact student0_1_ on student0_.student_key=student0_1_.Id WHERE student0_.student_key=@p0;@p0 = 1 [Type: Int32 (0:0:0)]
NHibernate: SELECT comments0_.student_key as student1_2_0_, comments0_.id as id2_2_0_, comments0_.idx as idx3_0_ FROM Comments comments0_ WHERE comments0_.student_key=@p0;@p0 = 1 [Type: Int32 (0:0:0)]
```

The `listMapper.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy)` that you already have there should do the trick.

I think that maybe you don't really have a Student with ID `2` in the database?
If that's the case, you will only see NHibernate issuing the first query (over Contact/Student) and it will not issue a query over Comments as the Student does not exist.

If you have a Student with ID `2` you should see the query to the Comments table right after the initial one.

If you like, you can try adding `listMapper.Fetch(CollectionFetchMode.Join)` to bring both the Student and Comments in the same query, although I wouldn't generally recommend this.

Comment: Yes, that's it, I don't have the entity in the database. Works perfectly otherwise.